# How to make start menu smaller

Tags: windows-10-preview, microsoft-surface-pro-3

I've had the small version of the start **menu** before on my computer before and somehow it changed back to the atrocious start **screen**. How do I change it back?

According to [this blog](http://winsupersite.com/windows-10/windows-10-tip-customize-start-menu), there's supposed to be a check box for that. Well, as the screen below shows, it's not present on my system.

Could it be affected by the desktop/tablet mode switch? How can I confirm which mode my computer is in at the moment? I only get a question if I should enter this or that mode but I get no yes or no button and I'm not notified of whether the change's been effected or not...

[image]

Comment: Which build # of Win10 are you on?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 How do I check it?

Comment: In the computer properties (Try Windows Key + Pause/Break to open it)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I have no such key on my Surface 3...

Answer (score 0):

> It is now a toggle button on the Start Menu/Screen itself. Open the screen and look on the top right for arrow boxes pointing outwards (if you're on the Start Menu) or inwards (if on the Start Screen)

[Source](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_update/use-the-start-menu-instead-of-the-start-screen/8992d195-73bf-4866-af8b-ac6e14b3c87d)

> I believe that option has been removed as of 9926. The functionality has
>    been replaced by allowing you to run the Start menu in full screen mode.
>
> Click the Start menu, then click the button in the top right (the one with
>    the 4 directional arrows on it).

[Source](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/18e093fa-75e8-4304-bf39-bf65feb45e2a/no-way-to-change-between-start-screen-and-start-menu?forum=WinPreview2014General)

Comment: Yeah, it's there. But sometimes it isn't... Tablet mode? How do I switch between desktop and tablet modes?!